# GeographyFromText and ST_SetSRID+ST_MakePoint different results?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, distance, geometry, spatial-database

Why am I getting different results?

```
SELECT ST_DISTANCE(
  ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(13.401111 52.383343)'), --berlin
  ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(9.997559 53.533778)') --hamburg
);
```

= 262077.401614256

```
SELECT ST_DISTANCE(
  ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(13.401111, 52.383343), 4326),
  ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(9.997559, 53.533778), 4326)
);
```

= 3.592724162238034

The first result looks a lot closer to reality ;-)

**Edit:** had to cast the points in the second query to geography.

```
SELECT ST_DISTANCE(
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(13.401111, 52.383343), 4326)::geography,
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(9.997559, 53.533778), 4326)::geography
);
```

Still don't really understand why I have to do this. Isn't SRID=4326 enough for ST_DISTANCE to know what type of point I am passing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ST_Distance ([folowing the documentation](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Distance.html)) - For **geometry** type Returns the 2-dimensional cartesian minimum distance (based on spatial ref) between two geometries **in projected units**. For **geography** type defaults to return spheroidal minimum distance between two geographies **in meters**.

So - if you'll feed it with geometry,4326 you'll get distance in units of 4326 which is degrees; if you'll feed it with geography you'll get distance in meters..